# Way to custom format the number such that text will be of some specified color

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I am trying to find a way to change the color of text after applying custom format in excel.

Lets suppose the value in my column are 2,3 and 1

[image]

and if I customize this cell by following formula

```
[<=1]0.0 "year";[>1]0.0 "years"
```

Now the cell will looks like

[image]

Now I wanted to change the color of "Year"/"years" word only to some red color, but not getting any way.

Search a lot and got only a way to change the font-color of full cell by some other color using this.

```
[Red][<=1]0.0 "year";[Red][>1]0.0 "years"
```

Please help to achieve this.

Note : **I don't want to use VBA for this.**

Comment: Does conditional formatting solve your problem?

Comment: No condition formatting changing the color of full text including digit.

Answer (score 0):

**[Range.NumberFormat property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.numberformat)** changes the appearance of the values in the cells, without changing the actual values. It can be used to change the color of an entire section of the [Number format code](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/number-format-codes-5026bbd6-04bc-48cd-bf33-80f18b4eae68?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)(i.e. positive numbers, negative numbers, zeros and text) as this code format does:

```
[Blue] #.0 "Positive";[Red] #.0 "Negative";[Green] - "Zero    ";[Magenta]@ "Text"
```

[image]

*However, it cannot change partially the color of a section.*

*Note that cells [B7] and [D7] have a `SUM` formula to add the ranges [B3:B6] and [D3:D6] respectively.*

**Using VBA:**
**[Range.Characters property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.characters)** can be used to change the appearance of the `Characters` of the text contents of a cell, as this code does for the range [B3:B6]:

```
Sub Characters_FontColor()
Dim Cll As Range, b As Byte

    For Each Cll In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TEST").Range("B3:B6")
        With Cll
            For b = 1 To Len(.Value)
                .Characters(b, 1).Font.ColorIndex = 2 + b
    Next: End With: Next

End Sub
```

[image]

Note that in the case of the cells in [B3:B5] the procedure changed the font color of the cell instead of each `Character` like in cell [B6], and that’s because the contents of the those cells are not text.

**Regarding Op’s requirements:**

> I am trying to find a way to change the color of text after applying custom format in excel.

- The color of text in a custom format can be changed for an entire section.

> Now I wanted to change the color of "Year"/"years" word only to some red color, but not getting any way.

- The color of text in a custom format cannot be partially changed within a section.

> Search a lot and got only a way to change the font-color of full cell by some other color using this.

- That custom format did not change the font color of the cell, it only changed the appearance of the sections within the custom format. To test this, check the font color of the cell and you'll see that it remains as `Automatic` or whatever it was before applying the custom formatting.

> I don't want to use VBA for this.

- *This cannot be done with VBA*. As mentioned before the custom format only changes the appearance of the cell, the value of the cell remains as entered, this allows the use of the `cells.value` in formulas. The use of `Characters` in VBA allows change the color of part of the text, but in order to use this the `cells.value` must be a text string, but then the `sum` of the cells would be zero. To test this apply the procedure `Characters_FontColor` to the range [D3:D6] and you'll see no change.

Comment: For my purpose the TL/DR answer is the finding "The color of text in a custom format cannot be partially changed within a section."

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you will be able to do it from the user interface. However, from the VBA it can be done:
http://vbadud.wordpress.com/2007/11/03/excel-vba-change-font-color-for-part-of-text/